# How to delete fitness.runs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

new to Facebook Open Graph here. I've been able to post fitness.runs from my iOS app. However, since they were test runs with a test course, I want to be able to delete them from Facebook.

How would I go about doing that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, not sure if this is the right way to do it... but I just grabbed the activity ID from those fitness.runs and deleted them using the Graph Explorer tool on developers.facebook.com. It looks like the test fitness.course and fitness.run, still exist when I view my Open Graph objects in the Open Graph object browser.